# Error when running google heat map in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, heatmap

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to use this plugin to create a heat map in googlemap `google_maps_flutter_heatmap 0.1.1+2`
But everytime I run the code, this error appears. I already added the APK KEY to the manifest file and tried `flutter clean` but its still the same.

```
E:\~MobileDev\flutter project\myproject\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:32: error: constructor GoogleMapsPlugin in class GoogleMapsPlugin cannot be applied to given types;
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapsPlugin());
                                   ^
  required: Registrar
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

EDIT:

I tried removing another plugin which is `google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.30` . And now it works. Does this mean there are conflicts between this two plugins? Is there anyway I can use them both?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct there are conflicts between the two packages because the name `GoogleMaps` exists in both packages: `google_maps_flutter_heatmap` and `google_maps_flutter`.

If you want to use both of the packages, you will need to import these packages using 'as prefix' to differentiate them from each other. For example:

```
import "package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart" as gmaps;
import "package:google_maps_flutter_heatmap/google_maps_flutter_heatmap.dart" as heatmap;
```

Then you can declare the `GoogleMap` by prepending one of the prefixes you use. Let's say, you want to use the `GoogleMap` inside of `google_maps_flutter` package. Then it will go like this:

```
gmaps.GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
),
```